# Precision of NVARCHAR2 column is 1.5 times lower than displayed by desc command

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, datatypes, oracle-sql-developer

I wanted to update precision of an `nvarchar2` column and came across an interesting case. I have tried to replicate it below:

```
create table test_table1
 (col1 nvarchar2(100));

table TEST_TABLE1 created.

desc test_table1
Name Null Type           
---- ---- -------------- 
COL1      NVARCHAR2(150)
```

We observed that the displayed precision of the *nvarchar2* column is 1.5 times the specified precision. So if I have to replicate the precision of a column of type `NVARCHAR2(375)`, then we need to declare it as `NVARCHAR2(250)`.

I tried searching for an explanation but couldn't find any. Does anyone have any idea on this please? We are using Oracle-11g, connecting with Oracle SQL Developer.

#### NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS

```
select * from NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;

+-------------------------+------------------------------+
|        PARAMETER        |            VALUE             |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| NLS_LANGUAGE            | AMERICAN                     |
| NLS_TERRITORY           | AMERICA                      |
| NLS_CURRENCY            | $                            |
| NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        | AMERICA                      |
| NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  | .,                           |
| NLS_CALENDAR            | GREGORIAN                    |
| NLS_DATE_FORMAT         | YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS        |
| NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       | AMERICAN                     |
| NLS_SORT                | BINARY                       |
| NLS_TIME_FORMAT         | HH.MI.SSXFF AM               |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    | DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM     |
| NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      | HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR           |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT | DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR |
| NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       | $                            |
| NLS_COMP                | BINARY                       |
| NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    | BYTE                         |
| NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     | FALSE                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

#### NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS

```
select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
|        PARAMETER        |           VALUE            |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| NLS_LANGUAGE            | AMERICAN                   |
| NLS_TERRITORY           | SWITZERLAND                |
| NLS_CURRENCY            | SFr.                       |
| NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        | SWITZERLAND                |
| NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  | .'                         |
| NLS_CHARACTERSET        | AL32UTF8                   |
| NLS_CALENDAR            | GREGORIAN                  |
| NLS_DATE_FORMAT         | DD.MM.RR                   |
| NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       | AMERICAN                   |
| NLS_SORT                | BINARY                     |
| NLS_TIME_FORMAT         | HH24:MI:SSXFF              |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    | DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF     |
| NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      | HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR          |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT | DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR |
| NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       | SF                         |
| NLS_COMP                | BINARY                     |
| NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    | BYTE                       |
| NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     | FALSE                      |
| NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  | UTF8                       |
| NLS_RDBMS_VERSION       | 11.2.0.4.0                 |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

#### nls_length_semantics

```
show parameter nls_length_semantics;
Show parameters query failed
```

****Resolution****

Thanks for the effort guys. The problem is indeed with `SQL Developer`.

I tried running it after connecting manually in Unix. Got correct result

```
create table test_table1
 (col1 nvarchar2(100));

Table created.

desc test_table1;
 Name  Null?   Type
 ---------------------------
 COL1          NVARCHAR2(100)
```

Thanks for both the answers. Thanks [Paul](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white) for declaring the bounty and thanks [jsapkota](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68931/jsapkota) and [Giova](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/70726/giova) for taking your time and helping me out.

Comment: @JSapkota - Thanks for looking at it. I understand that the actual value is `100` but somehow it is showing as `150` due to some NLS settings. I updated my question with both `session parameter` and `database parameter` values. Also the `show parameter nls_length_semantics` query is not working for me. I pasted that too in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure that this is a problem of SQL Developer...
Retry to desc table after issuing:

```
alter session set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS='CHAR';
```

Is correct now? If not try to desc the table using sqlplus on the database server bypassing the Oracle Listener:

```
>export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_SWITZERLAND.AL32UTF8 
>export ORACLE_SID=<YOURINSTANCESID>
>sqlplus / as sysdba
>sqlplus>desc owner.table
```

If the result is not correct, execute:

> SQLPLUS>alter session set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS='CHAR';
>   SQLPLUS>desc owner.table

If you can'tdo it on the server try the same with you sqldeveloper (but you will not bypass the listener):

```
>set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_SWITZERLAND.AL32UTF8 
>C:\oracle\client\product\12.1.0\client\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldevelope‌​rW.exe
```

Change the `sqldevelope‌​rW.exe` path.
Let me know
When you declare a nvarchar2 field, the size is expressed ALWAYS in char. With desc command you are viewing the size in bytes. Sqldeveloper in some way is not able to display the vlaue in char. Also you can try to update your sqldevleoper version.

Giova

Note: I do not find Offical Oracle documentation about but this wiki explains better this behavior of sql developer:

[Setting NLS LENGTH SEMANTICS](http://wiki.loopback.org/index.php/Setting_NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS)

In the past I found the same problem with plsqldeveloper and other clients. Maybe the most updated versions works correctly.

Comment: You were spot on in assuming it was `SQL Developer` issuer. Unfortunately I am not supposed to changed the session parameter, but in Unix I got the correct result. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = UTF8`. I simulated the same table in a different database with `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16`. The describe statement shows the correct length as defined while creating table.

UTF8 can be 1, 2, 3 or 6 bytes / character, any AL32UTF8 character that is 4 bytes will be stored as 2 time 3 bytes in UTF8. If you want to store 1 byte character in UTF8 it takes 1.5 bytes (1*1.5=1.5).

For further details, see:

[AL32UTF8 / UTF8 (Unicode) Database Character Set Implications [ID 788156.1]](http://m.blog.itpub.net/17252115/viewspace-753243)

Comment: This confirms that the mismatching view is because of sqldeveloper and/or NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS value (bytes and not char)

Comment: @Giova. Have you tested it? i mean if you change the semantics and the length is consistent as define while creating table. I changed semantics and tested many times with utf8 it still shows the length 1.5 times larger. So i tested it by changing nchar_characterset to al16utf16 is the only next options available for nchar_characterset.

Comment: I tested it sjth some other tools that ade not vompletely aware of nvarchar2. I can send you a list later. I check sqldeveloper foc a f Metsljnk. This "issue" is not reported but this behavior,  if expected, should be dicumented.... at the moment I don't hsve a csi in this scope to open a sr  about this problem.

Comment: @JSapkota - Thanks for the explanation on why UTF8 takes 1.5 times the size. Only doubt still in my mind is that I see `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  UTF8` in my unix session too, but I am getting correct values when doing a describe on `unix` session, but not in `SQL Developer`.

Comment: @Utsav as Giova commented it must be the issue related to the SQL Developer. I also tested it with SQL*PLUS the length was correctly shown.