# Varchar2 datatypes are longer than expected

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

When I run the following script :

```
create table tbl1 (
col1 varchar2(30),
col2 varchar2(50),
col3 number(4,2)
);
desc tbl1;
alter table tbl1 modify (col1 varchar2(35));
desc tbl1;
drop table tbl1;
```

Here is the output I get :

```
Table created.
TABLE tbl1
 Name                                      Null?    Type                        
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               VARCHAR2(120)               
 COL2                                               VARCHAR2(200)               
 COL3                                               NUMBER(4,2)                 
Table altered.
TABLE tbl1
 Name                                      Null?    Type                        
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               VARCHAR2(140)               
 COL2                                               VARCHAR2(200)               
 COL3                                               NUMBER(4,2)                 
Table dropped.
```

Can somebody explain me why the column lengths for varchar2 would be 4 times larger than they should ?

Comment: You might find this useful [Precision of NVARCHAR2 column is 1.5 times lower than displayed by desc command](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125862/precision-of-nvarchar2-column-is-1-5-times-lower-than-displayed-by-desc-command/126269#126269)

Comment: Oh so this is basically a characterset non-issue. Also, I'm using TOAD for Oracle 12.8

Comment: The NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is set to AL16UTF16.

Comment: according to your question you are having trouble with varchar not nvarchar right? so if your database is set to non Unicode characterset and you want to store Unicode characters then you can set nls_nvarchar_characterset. i wanted to know the output of `select * from nls_database_parameters` and `select * from nls_session_parameters`

Comment: have you tried same thing using sql*plus? whats the different or the result is same?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a combination of your NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'CHAR' system parameter and a character set defined that is 4 bytes per character.

Can you check on what your NLS settings are?

Comment: nls_length_semantics                 string   CHAR is what the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS is set at

Comment: What character set are you using? NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'CHAR' means that it will make the varchar2 columns created during that time equal to 1 character instead of 1 byte. Your character set settings are probably such that each char = 4 bytes. DESC is showing you the size in bytes because NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS is something that can be changed on the fly.

Comment: The NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is set to AL16UTF16. Does that means 4 bytes per char ?

Comment: Yes, it does. If you are worried about DESC command showing the same  thing you type in, you can use the NVARCHAR2 field, but the result is the same. Using that char set, if you want to store 30 chars, it needs 120 bytes to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Each character required 4 bytes to store. That is the reason it showing as 4 times. So `varchar2(30)` requires 120 bytes to store in the database.

So in the describe command it showing the memory allocation sizes.